# validate object by it's methods

Tags: ruby, validation

My app lets user choose his own data adapter class. He can pass it as an object of his custom class. Then I check if that object has specific methods needed to work as a valid data adapter. It looks like this:

```
def valid_object?(object)
  object.respond_to?(:method_1) &&
  object.respond_to?(:method_2) &&
  object.respond_to?(:method_3) &&
  object.respond_to?(:method_4) &&
  object.respond_to?(:method_5) &&
  object.respond_to?(:method_6) &&
  object.respond_to?(:method_7)
end
```

It doesn't look to good. Is there a way to write it better? Without so much repetition?

I heard that other languages have something called interfaces that let them check if object has specific methods. So maybe there are better ways to check if object is valid in ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it using the `Enumerable#all?` method, like this:

```
[:method1, :method2, ..., :method7].all? { |m| object.respond_to?(m) }
```

Comment: So simple (and fast) yet I didn't think about such solution. Thank you very much :)